# Binding identical events on newly appended AJAX elements

Tags: jquery, binding, control-flow

I'm trying to port an infinite scrolling site to mobile devices, disabling the AJAX scroll and replacing it with AJAX "more" buttons. I'm having problems understanding how to bind the initial click events to the subsequent instances of the "more" buttons.

I'm still green at programming, but know enough that if I'm doing something twice, it's wrong. How can I bind the events inside of .on() to each instance of "more" as they're dynamically added to the page?

JS:

```
$('.more-link').on('click', function(){

    var url = $(this).attr('href');        
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    $(this).remove();

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('.infinite-container').append(data);

        // Callback for .on()
        }).done(function (){

        // Add visibility for "more" buttons 
        $('.more-link').css({'visibility': 'visible'});  

        // Here's where I'm repeating myself       
        $('.more-link').on('click', function(){

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).removeAttr('href');
            $(this).remove();

            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $('.infinite-container').append(data);
            })
        });

    });
});
```

Any insights and efficiency would be appreciated.

Edit: I should add that the "more" links are a part of the `data` appended to the end of the container at each call. The way I currently have it set up, functionality breaks on the third call.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. JQuery's .on() has extra parameters that allow for biding targeted elements added dynamically later on. In this case, adding the bind to a specific selector within a parent element (like `document`) accomplishes the task:

```
$(element).on('event', 'selector', function(event) {...});
```

So, for the example in the question, code should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.more-link', function(){..stuff..});
```